# Display two texts in a row without spacing, but maintaining a TextOverflow.elipsis

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to display a collapsed text with a `more` tag on the right of it.

[image]

I'm also trying to make the width of this row dynamic, so it would display as many characters as the screen width allows.

I almost achieved this effect by the following code, which can be run on [dart.pad](https://dartpad.dev/):

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue,
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(children: [
      Flexible(
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.red,
          child: const Text(
            'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.',
            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      const Text(' more'),
    ]);
  }
}
```

The problem I'm facing is that, depending on the width of the screen, the `more` tag may be spaced from the first text:

[image]

It seems that the "policy" of my row is to expand all the available space, and then give the extra space to the right of the first widget. Actually, I would prefer to not have this extra space, and remove it from the right of my row.

Comment: you want to remove padding inside the container or red area?

Comment: @Mahi I want to remove the dynamic padding inside the red area, at the right of the ellipsed text

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
Row(
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.red,
            child: Text(
              'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.',
              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Text('more'),
      ],
    ),
```

Result Screen-> [image]

### Updated Answer

Try to add [**`readmore`**](https://pub.dev/packages/readmore) package

Add below **dependency** in your `pubspec.yaml` file

```
readmore: ^2.1.0
```

import the package:

```
import 'package:readmore/readmore.dart';
```

Your Widget:

```
ReadMoreText(
          'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.',
          trimLines: 1,
          colorClickableText: Colors.pink,
          trimMode: TrimMode.Line,
          trimCollapsedText: 'more',
          trimExpandedText: 'less',
          moreStyle: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 14,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          ),
        ),
```

Result Screen with more -> [image]

Result screen with less -> [image]

Comment: Hi, Ravindra. Thanks for contributing. Changing the `Flexible` widget for an `Expanded` one doesn't change the UI. It doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: The screenshot you took registers a dynamic width in which both Texts are close, but if you increase/decrease the width of your screen or from your parent class, you will see that, depending on the eclipsed word, the space in between the texts still remains.

Comment: @MigueldeSousa I have update the answer hope its help to you.